# Cannot access Recovery Mode on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, recovery

I am using a model A1278 Mac and I need to reinstall the OS on it, or reset it. I am attempting to open the recovery mode by using the Cmd + R method but that did not work, I then attempted to use the Option method. That too did not work.

I am out of options and very, very inexperienced in the Mac OS, thus any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Unsure on the OS X version I am using.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying you have model A1234, you could mention what type of Mac it it (i.e. MacBook, iMac, MacBook Air...)

Comment: Along with if you can even get into Macintosh HD, and if you could tell us the OS from the About This Mac menu item in Finder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original A1278 MacBook Pro unibody was shipped with Mac OS X 10.5.5 (Leopard).

From [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca)

> OVERVIEW
>
> Introduced    October 2008 Discontinued   June 2009 Model
>   Identifier    MacBook5,1 Model Number A1278 EMC   2254 Order
>   Number    MB466LL/A (2.0 GHz), MB467LL/A (2.4 GHz) Initial Price  $1,299
>   (2.0 GHz) $1,599 (2.4 GHz) Support Status Vintage Case    Precision
>   aluminum unibody Weight and Dimensions    4.5 lbs., 0.95" H x 12.78" W x
>   8.94" D PROCESSOR
>
> Processor Intel Core 2 Duo (P7350, P8600) ("Penryn") Processor
>   Speed 2.0 or 2.4 GHz Architecture 64-bit Number of Cores  2 Cache 3 MB
>   on chip shared L2 cache System Bus    1066 MHz STORAGE AND MEDIA
>
> Storage   160, 250, or 320 GB (5400-rpm SATA) or 128 or 256 GB (SSD)
>   Media Slot-loading 8x SuperDrive (DVD±R DL/DVD±RW/CD-RW) KEYBOARD AND
>   TRACKPAD
>
> Trackpad  Multi-Touch trackpad Keyboard   Full size (78 (U.S.) or 79
>   (ISO) keys incl. 12 function, 4 arrow). Illuminated keyboard on 2.4
>   GHz

You may find some useful information in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103960/120171).  The MacBook you have was shipped with a DVD that contained the installation and recovery files.  Whether or not you have access to this DVD, you will have to [purchase **OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard** from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) in order to upgrade to the latest supported OS which is 10.10 Yosemite.

#### Apple Support:

> Upgrading from OS X Leopard If you’re running Leopard and would like
>   to upgrade to OS X Yosemite, first you’ll need to upgrade to OS X Snow
>   Leopard. You can purchase OS X Snow Leopard [here.](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard)

While Yosemite is a free upgrade Snow Leopard still carries a $19.99 USD price tag.  [See Apple's Upgrade Support page for details.](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/)

Depending on your investment, the price may be worth considering.

---

See also this answer:

> [Can I download Mac OS X for a used MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204388/120171)